# problem with configuring gobject-introspection for pygobject and pygtk

Tags: python, pygtk, gobject, pygobject

i am trying to install pygtk on my mac which then asked me to install pygobject which then asked me to get gobject-introspection . the problem i have in this installation is while configuring it shows this error :

> checking for FFI... no
>   checking for ffi.h... configure: error: ffi.h not found

please do help me with this as i need to get gtk .

/usr/include/ffi->location of ffi.h

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
export FFI_CFLAGS=/usr/include
export FFI_LIBS=/usr/lib
```

then

```
./configure
```

I hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I initially found this compile failure while assembling GLib (all versions I tried that were more recent than 2.28.7), but I again encountered it with gobject; and it appears related to several other packages' build failures:

- http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/guile-gtk-general/2006-10/msg00010.html
- [Weird error when installing GLIB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113457/weird-error-when-installing-glib)
- http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-gnome/2011-August/026346.html

I tried following the advice provided in all of these threads (as the solutions discussed are largely the same) with no success.

The Final Solution: a complete recompile and install of GCC (4.7.2)

*Why did compiling GCC (4.7.2) solve the issue?*

I found this post in the Debian Bug Archive: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=523869

While reading, I noted that my system was using an affected version of GCC to compile my various sources (from an FC9 installation on a relic laptop).

I chose 4.7.2 as my goal because it was, at the time of this writing, the most current build in the stable tree.  I'm relatively sure that a simple package install of a recent GCC on your system will yield the same results (so long as you get 4.3.5-4 or later), but I haven't tested this as there are understandably no such packages for an FC9 install.  The package route has many potential positive aspects beyond being easy, please read below..

**Important Note:** If you are trying to compile GCC, you'll probably need a working (and current) glibc enviroment...  *Please read up on this complication* **BEFORE** *you start the manual process:* http://cygwin.com/ml/libc-alpha/2012-02/msg00646.html

The workaround is to find a Glibc version that predates the commit noted in the article above (i went with 2.14), compile GCC 4.5 with that installed (i chose 4.5.3 due to release proximity with glibc 2.14), and then start the process again with current Glibc and GCC...  best of luck!

- GCC: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gcc/
- Glibc: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/
- Binutils: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/binutils/

Answer (score 0):

ffi.h is provided by the package libffi-dev, which is actually from the gcc source package. and most probably it's available for linux.