# Weird error when installing GLIB

Tags: installation, glib

When installing `GLIB` I get this error:

> Making install in .
>    ./install-sh -c -d '/usr/bin'
>    /usr/bin/install -c glib-gettextize '/usr/bin'
>    ./install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/share/glib-2.0/gettext'
>    /usr/bin/install -c mkinstalldirs '/usr/local/share/glib-2.0/gettext'
>    ./install-sh -c -d '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
>    /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 glib-2.0.pc gobject-2.0.pc gmodule-2.0.pc gmodule-export-2.0.pc gmodule-no-export-2.0.pc gthread-2.0.pc gio-2.0.pc gio-unix-2.0.pc '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
>   Making install in m4macros
>   make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
>    .././install-sh -c -d '/usr/local/share/aclocal'
>    /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 glib-2.0.m4 glib-gettext.m4 gsettings.m4 '/usr/local/share/aclocal'
>   Making install in glib
>     GEN      glib_probes.o
>   Usage: dtrace [-aACeFHlqSvVwZ] [-arch i386|x86_64] [-b bufsz] [-c cmd] [-D name[=def]]
>       [-I path] [-L path] [-o output] [-p pid] [-s script] [-U name]
>       [-x opt[=val]]

```
[-P provider [[ predicate ] action ]]
[-m [ provider: ] module [[ predicate ] action ]]
[-f [[ provider: ] module: ] func [[ predicate ] action ]]
[-n [[[ provider: ] module: ] func: ] name [[ predicate ] action ]]
[-i probe-id [[ predicate ] action ]] [ args ... ]

predicate -> '/' D-expression '/'
   action -> '{' D-statements '}'

-arch Generate programs and Mach-O files for the specified architecture

-a  claim anonymous tracing state
-A  generate plist(5) entries for anonymous tracing
-b  set trace buffer size
-c  run specified command and exit upon its completion
-C  run cpp(1) preprocessor on script files
-D  define symbol when invoking preprocessor
-e  exit after compiling request but prior to enabling probes
-f  enable or list probes matching the specified function name
-F  coalesce trace output by function
-h  generate a header file with definitions for static probes
-H  print included files when invoking preprocessor
-i  enable or list probes matching the specified probe id
-I  add include directory to preprocessor search path
-l  list probes matching specified criteria
-L  add library directory to library search path
-m  enable or list probes matching the specified module name
-n  enable or list probes matching the specified probe name
-o  set output file
-p  grab specified process-ID and cache its symbol tables
-P  enable or list probes matching the specified provider name
-q  set quiet mode (only output explicitly traced data)
-s  enable or list probes according to the specified D script
-S  print D compiler intermediate code
-U  undefine symbol when invoking preprocessor
-v  set verbose mode (report stability attributes, arguments)
-V  report DTrace API version
-w  permit destructive actions
-x  enable or modify compiler and tracing options
-Z  permit probe descriptions that match zero probes
```

> make[1]: *** [glib_probes.o] Error 2
>   make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1

Edit:
After following Nelson's advice, this error came up, towards the end:

```
gclosure.c:29:17: error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
gclosure.c:1128: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
gclosure.c: In function 'value_from_ffi_type':
gclosure.c:1217: error: 'ffi_arg' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1217: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
gclosure.c:1217: error: for each function it appears in.)
gclosure.c:1217: error: 'int_val' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1217: error: expected expression before ')' token
gclosure.c: At top level:
gclosure.c:1296: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '*' token
gclosure.c: In function 'g_cclosure_marshal_generic':
gclosure.c:1391: error: 'ffi_type' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1391: error: 'rtype' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1394: error: 'atypes' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1397: error: 'ffi_cif' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1397: error: expected ';' before 'cif'
gclosure.c:1405: warning: implicit declaration of function 'value_to_ffi_type'
gclosure.c:1409: error: 'ffi_type_void' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1412: error: 'ffi_arg' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1415: error: expected expression before ')' token
gclosure.c:1427: error: 'ffi_type_pointer' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1451: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ffi_prep_cif'
gclosure.c:1451: error: 'cif' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1451: error: 'FFI_DEFAULT_ABI' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1451: error: 'FFI_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1454: warning: implicit declaration of function 'ffi_call'
gclosure.c: In function 'g_cclosure_marshal_generic_va':
gclosure.c:1469: error: 'ffi_type' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1469: error: 'rtype' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1472: error: 'atypes' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1476: error: 'ffi_cif' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1476: error: expected ';' before 'cif'
gclosure.c:1489: error: 'ffi_type_void' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1492: error: 'ffi_arg' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1495: error: expected expression before ')' token
gclosure.c:1504: error: 'ffi_type_pointer' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1525: warning: implicit declaration of function 'va_to_ffi_type'
gclosure.c:1547: error: 'cif' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1547: error: 'FFI_DEFAULT_ABI' undeclared (first use in this function)
gclosure.c:1547: error: 'FFI_OK' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[3]: *** [libgobject_2_0_la-gclosure.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [install] Error 2
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

Edit: Decided to add `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to bash .profile in my user. Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it can't find the `dtrace` command, and according to [glib building](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.28/glib-building.html) docs:

> - The optional support for DTrace requires the sys/sdt.h header, which is provided by SystemTap on Linux. To build GLib without DTrace, use
>     the --disable-dtrace configure option.
> - The optional support for SystemTap can be disabled with the --disable-systemtap configure option.

So if you're not interested in SystemTap support, just disable it when running `configure`, like so:

```
configure --disable-dtrace  --disable-systemtap
```

Comment: Worked to a point; see edit to original post.

Comment: It seems the new error is glib can't find the header files of libffi. You have to install libffi dev package so ffi.h is installed and glib can find it.

Comment: I _already_ built libffi myself and specified it's location in my home dir under LIBFFI_LIBS.

Comment: Take a look https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2011-November/msg00001.html it seems very similar to your build error.

Comment: Tried what it suggested and it didn't work. According to my attempt at installing libffi, libffi is in /usr/pkgconfig, which is in my path for pkgconfig, yet when I try to configure following that it says it can't find it. Any clue why not?

Comment: Add the shell variable to what? The bash .profile?

Comment: Try to add it to your current session, like `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/pkgconfig` .Make sure to run it again when you switch user to root to run `make install`